# Read local file system with Java from Docker container

Tags: java, docker

I have a java app running on a docker container on mac osx. I want to access a file on a certain directory within the local file system using `Paths.get('/Users/username/folder')`

I am getting errors because docker is reading from its vm directory. How will I within a java app access the local file system while running the app in docker?

Comment: is the directory on the host or inside the container? If it's on the host, you need a parent of your target directory mounted as docker volume in the container

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can share the folder in the host machine with the container:

```
docker run -v your/host/folder:/your/container/folder ....
```

And then you can use `Paths.get('/your/container/folder')`

If you map the host folder in the same folder inside the container then you don't have to take care about it in the java code `docker run -v your/folder:/your/folder ....`. You also have to keep in mind issues with permissions...

[Official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)