# Run a bat file on a host machine, from inside a java container, using a rest call

Tags: java, angular, docker, batch-file, containers

The goal is that the user can click on a button on the UI to execute a C++ desktop application that can to be started using a bat file.
And since it seems impossible to run a bat file from a typescript controller (Angular) because of security reasons, I was thinking that when the button is clicked, a message (post request) is sent to the backend, which is a java container, and this container will communicate with the host machine to execute the bat file.

Is there a clean way to do this ?

I already checked this:

[Forward Rest calls inside the container to wiremock running on host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54451883/forward-rest-calls-inside-the-container-to-wiremock-running-on-host-machine)

[Read local file system with Java from Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786533/read-local-file-system-with-java-from-docker-container)

[Require('child_process') => cannot find Require / child_process + launch .bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721793/requirechild-process-cannot-find-require-child-process-launch-bat)

To improve to process in the future,I may also have to send some parameters.

Comment: A container can't see any of the host filesystem, run commands on the host, or interact with the host desktop at all.  You might need to run your launcher application outside a container.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt it is possible from just within a container.

Docker containers are a way to separate processes from each other. If an application could exit that container so easily it would be considered a bug on the container platform.

This gets different if the container has help from outside/to the outside world. For example, if the container has access to talk to the docker daemon,  it could ask that process to spawn your script. And it would run in another container on the same docker host.
And if your container could talk to another application via network, that one could trigger another process inside a container, outside a container, on the same host or a network host, ...